# How can I correlate dynamically changing left and right values in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter,

How to corelation left and right values are dynamic.
Ex: Rakesh Kumar Choudhury

Rakesh And Choudhury is the dynamic. Kumar is Staic
How to corelate the value in jmeter.

I am try all posibility, not have corelation. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration:

- Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `foo`
- Regular Expression: `(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)`
- Template: `$2$`

This way it will extract the 2nd [match group](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) and store it into `foo` variable.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)